# How many ways can we get an even number of tails from two groups of people?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider two groups of people: one containing $N$ persons and the other containing $M$. Each person is asked to toss a coin. What is the probability that each group gets an even number of tails?

Please walk me through the derivation. Thank you.

My initial guess: Probably something of the form

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{?} {{?}\choose{2n}} \big/{2^{N+M}} \,?$$

---

[Motivation: Toric code in Quantum Computation. :) ]

Comment: Are all the tosses independent?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes.

Comment: Suppose you have 100 people and 99 have tossed their coins. Suppose the number of tails amongst these 99 tosses is odd. What is the probability that when the 100th person has tossed then the total number of tails is even?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It should be half.

Comment: So can you see what the probability that out of $N$ tosses one gets an even number of tails?

Comment: A useful identity:  $ {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 2} + {n \choose 4} + \cdots = {n \choose 1} + {n \choose 3} + {n \choose 5} + \cdots = 2^{n-1}.$  (To prove it, expand $(1 + x)^n$ and $(1 - x)^n$ using the binomial expansion, then set $x = 1$.)

Comment: I deleted my comment, as I was answering a different question.  For the question you are asking the answer is simply $\frac 12$ as you can toss the first $N-1$ coins however you like and then adjust the parity with the final throw, as remarked by @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you for sharing. Do you know of any identity for ${n \choose 0} + \frac{1}{2!}{n \choose 2} + \frac{1}{4!}{n \choose 4} + \cdots=?$ Equivalently, ${n \choose 1} + \frac{1}{3!}{n \choose 3} + \frac{1}{5!}{n \choose 5} + \cdots=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break it into steps.

Step $(1)$: what is the probability that the number of tails in $K$ coin tosses is even? Hint: what is the probability that the number of tails in $K$ coin tosses is *exactly* some integer $j$?

Step $(2)$: What is the probability that each group has an even number of tails symoultaneously? Hint: use independence!

---

Let $E_{j,K}$ be the event that exactly $j$ of the $K$ coin tosses are tails; we wish to calculate the probability $p_{j,K}=\mathbb{P}\left(E_{j,K}\right)$.
It can be found as follows:
choose $j$ of the $K$ coin tosses to be tails, in $\binom{K}{j}$ ways; the remaining (unchosen) tosses are heads.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between these choices and qualifying sets of $K$ coin tosses.
Moreover, each such choice has a ${\left(\frac12\right)}^K$ probability of occurring.
The total probability is hence

$$p_{j,K}=\binom{K}j\cdot\frac1{2^K}$$

Now, since for $j_1\neq j_2$ the events $E_{j_1,K}$ and $E_{j_2,K}$ are disjoint, we have that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(E_{j_1,K}\cup E_{j_2,K}\right)=p_{j_1,K}+p_{j_2,K}$$

Therefore, for the probability that the number of tails in $K$ coin tosses be even, we need only sum the $p_{j,K}$ over even $j$.

Comment: Is the answer to step (1) the following: $$\sum_{j=0}^{K/2} {K \choose {2j}} \frac{1}{(2j)! \ 2^K}?$$

Comment: Almost. What happens if $K$ is odd?

Comment: We sum up to $(K-1)/2?$

Comment: Yes! More succintly, $\lfloor K/2\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks. So for step (2), we just multiply the two probabilities, right? :)

Comment: You're welcome, and correct.

Comment: I should note however, that the expression for step $(1)$ *can* be simplified. Look at Michael Seifert's comment; it's a well-known identity of binomial numbers/Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't seen the $\frac1{(2j)!}$ in the answer. I will edit it with a proper explanation on where the answer comes from and why that term isn't there.

Comment: I added it to correct for the overcounting that happens due to indistinguishability of repeated heads when interchanged.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, very clear. Thank you very much. I had confused the notation $n \choose k$ with permutation $^nP_k = n!/(n-k)!$ which is why I kept dividing by the extra factor.